# My HTC Tmobile - G2 wifi turns off cicle

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, htc-desire-z

I dont Know why when I turn on my WIFI it automaticly turn off after a few seconds!

I have HTC VISION G2, Cianogenmod, 2.3.7
VISION PVT ENG s-OFF
HBOOT-0.76.2000 (PC10...)
MICROP-0425
RADIO-26-02-01-15_M2
eMMc-boot
Aug 20 2010, 16:51:01

Kernel 2.6.32.17-g814e0a1 htc-kernel@and18-2 #1
Build number 1.19.531.1 CL255798 release-keys
Baseband version 12.22.60.09bU_26.02.01.15_M2

It say "Unable to scan for networks"

Comment: Try rebooting your wifi-router and also check your logcat and kernel's log for clues :)

Comment: If the Wifi itself is turned off automatically, it looks more like a problem with the Baseband (radio image) to me than with the router. No WiFi in reach wouldn't turn Wifi off. "Unable to **scan** for networks" suggests this as well (it's not that it didn't *find* anything, it was not even able to *scan*).